# Create constant sized vector of constant sized vectors

Tags: c++, c++11, memory, vector, allocation

I am trying to learn C++. Currently I ran into a tutorial, which mentioned how to create a constant sized vector like this: `vector <int> v(10);` Now I'm wondering how to create a constant sized vector of constant sized vectors, something like: `vector <vector <int> (10)> v(10);` This code doesn't work, so I wanted to ask is there a way do something like this and if there is, how?

Comment: Why do you want to? Don't you *really* just want to use `std::array<std::array<int, 10>, 10>`? Or better yet, `std::array<int, 100>` and do some math on each indexed access?

Comment: To be honest I want a matrix, (2D Array), size of which will be depended on the input. something like:   int n; cin >>n; int arr[n][n]. But the problem is: I can't pass this to function. So I want to make same thing to vector to pass it to functions.

Comment: With `std::vector<int> v(10)` you get a vector with is construed with 10 element, not a "constant sized vector"; if you write `std::vector<int> v(10); v.push_back(0);` you get 11 element in `v`: the initial 10 and the one added with `push_back()`.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I just couldn't formulate it correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could

```
vector<vector<int>> v(10, vector<int>(10));
```

i.e. construct the [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) with 10 copies of elements with value `std::vector<int>(10)`.

Note that for `std::vector` the size is not constant, it might be changed when element(s) are inserted or erased, 10 is just the initial size when `v` and its elements get initialized. On the other hand, the size of [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) is constant, it's specified at compile-time and can't be changed at run-time.

Comment: Just exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 3):

You can't have a *constant sized vector of constant sized vectors* without writing your own class wrapper of some kind. Use the more appropriate [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) container for the task:

```
std::array<std::array<int, 10>, 10> arr;
```

Comment: The other answer above just told me the thing I wanted.

Comment: Yes, I didn't formulate it right, but by my example, it was pretty obvious what I wanted. No offense sir.